# how to find coordinates of a point perpendicular to a line?

Tags: geometry

The point P is at the foot of the perpendicular from the point a(0,3) to the line $y=3x$

1) find the equation of the line AP and find the coordinates of P

I have found the equation of the line which is $3y = x - 9$, but unable to find the coordinates of P. Could anyone guide me? 
Also, 
Show that  the line $y=3x$ is parallel to the tangent of the graph of $y=x^2 - 7 x +2$
Thanks

Comment: [Here's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a quick guide to writing math on this site. If your questions are more readable people are more likely to respond to them!

Comment: $P$ is the intersection of the two lines.

Comment: And there are infinitely many tangents to that graph. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @G-man: Probably about the one that is parallel to the line $y=3x$ ;-)

Comment: @celtschk that's all right but the question still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @G-man: There's a reason why I ended that comment with a smiley.

Comment: that's the way the question was given. can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Your equation of the perpendicular is wrong. The slope parameter of a perpendicular to a straight line $y=mx+q$ is $m'= -\dfrac{1}{m}$.

Correct this mistake and find the intersection point of the two straight lines, that is your $P$.

As noted in the comments your second question is confused. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If AP is the line perpendicular to the line y= 3x, then the slope of AP is $\frac {-1}{3}$.

You are required to check your result again because of the following:-

This means that the equation of AP is 3y + x = some constant, which is found to be 9 by the fact that the line passes through A(0, 3).

To find P, you need to solve the two equations. This will give you P = (0.9, 2.7).

For the second part, there are many points on the given graph. Each point has its own value of slope. Your question did not say which point. This make the comparison with y = 3x impossible. I guess that point is (5, -8).

Comment: Which of the two equations do i need to get P? I have the answers which are 9/10 and 27/10, but i have no idea how to get there..

Comment: One is the equation just found (i.e. 3y + x = 9) and the other is the one that was given (i.e. y = 3x).

Comment: sorry to ask again, but i'm confused, what do i need to substitute in order to get the coordinates?

Comment: Just put y = 3x in 3y + x = 9 to get 3(3x) + x = 9.